# UIAlertController's Dismissal

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uialertcontroller

I've implemented a navigation mediator singleton in my application. The mediator keeps a reference to the primary view controller to launch view controller transitions from. So to present a view controller, the consumer would call the navigation mediator to do this. Same with dismissal so that it can reset the primary view controller.

The problem I am running into is with presenting a UIAlertController. I cannot dismiss this controller through my navigation mediator because it is dismissed automatically when a button is tapped, therefore losing the ability to reset the primary view controller when it is dismissed.

The only solution I've come up with is the create an extension on UIAlertController to override viewWillDisappear which resets the primary view controller like below. Is there a way to cancel the default dismissal behaviour?

```
extension UIAlertController {

    public override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        NavigationMediator.resetPrimaryViewController(self.presentingViewController)
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

No, but you can respond to the event before it will finish. UIALertViewDelegate. alertView:willDismissWithButtonIndex:

Else build your own AlertView.

Comment: UIAlertView is deprecated in iOS8. It is recommended to support UIAlertController. Thanks though.

Comment: Deprecated doesn't mean its wrong. It is just a warning.